# Chemfig - Proper Vertical Aligning in Chemical Reactions

Tags: formatting, chemfig

I have the following chemical equation in Chemfigs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\begin{document}

\schemestart
2
\chemfig{-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]OH}
\arrow
\chemfig{-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]} + \ch{CO_2} + \ch{H_2O}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

The problem is I can't get the proper vertical alignment with this code. How can alignment be achieved in Chemfig package?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! I took the liberty of completing your code into a compilable document. I hope you don't mind? The code gives a horizontal reaction. What exactly do you want to have vertically aligned? Do you want the compounds to be vertically centered with respect to each other?

Comment: Thanks for the correction, it's appreciated. I would like to get vertically aligned arrow, stoichiometry coefficients and the plus sign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since compounds are per default centered with respect to arrow in `chemfig`'s schemes I usually use an invisible arrow (type `0`) with length 0 (`\arrow{0}[,0]`, the second optional argument scales the arrow relative to the basic length, the “compoundsep”) to center compounds:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}

\begin{document}

Before:\medskip

\schemestart
2
\chemfig{-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]OH}
\arrow
\chemfig{-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]}
+ \ch{CO2} + \ch{H2O}
\schemestop

\bigskip
After:\medskip

\schemestart
2 \arrow{0}[,0]
\chemfig{-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]OH}
\arrow
\chemfig{-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]}
\arrow{0}[,0]
+ \ch{CO2} + \ch{H2O}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]