# Vertical alignment of molecules

Tags: chemfig

```
\begin{scheme}[h]
\centering
 %\setcrambond{3pt}{1pt}{1pt}
%\setbondoffset{3pt}
 \scriptsize\chemfig{(-[::60]R_1)(=[::180]O)-[::-60]O-[::-60]-[::60](-[::60]O-[::-60](-     [::60]R_2)(=[::-60]O))-[::-60]-[::60]O-[::-60](=[::60]O)(-[::-60]R_3)} + H_2O
 \chemrel{<->}
 \scriptsize\chemfig{(-[::60]R_1)(=[::180]O)-[::-60]O}
 \chemsign{+}
 \scriptsize\chemfig{(-[::60]R_1)(=[::180]O)-[::-60]O}
 \chemsign{+}
 \scriptsize\chemfig{(-[::60]R_1)(=[::180]O)-[::-60]O}
 \chemsign{+}
 \scriptsize\chemfig{(-[::60]R_1)(=[::180]O)-[::-60]O}
 \caption{reaction}
 \label{sn:reaction}
 \end{scheme}
```

[image]
How can I achieve that vertical alignment? I looked through the manual however there seemed no special command to mark the branch or molecule which everything else should align at.
Also, why is the O italic?

I saw a solution with invisible arrows but it seems like it doesn't work here. `\arrow{0}[,0]` will result in `[,0]` being written before my equation.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `chemfig`, but I would bet that the `_` is setting off math-mode for the following text—thus the `O` is italicized. I don't think `chemfig` is meant to handle the standard notation in this way; I would look for an alternative in the manual (or *maybe* you can use `\ch` from `mhchem`… *maybe*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't how how if this is the right way, to mark my questions as answered. however I found the solutionen. As mentionend above I already came across `\arrow{0}[,0]` the trick. 
I had to use:

```
\begin{scheme}
\schemestart
[...]
\schemestop
\end{scheme}
```

Original Question: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115269/chemfig-proper-vertical-aligning-in-chemical-reactions)